# Show that if a subgroup $H$ of $A_4$ contains at least $7$ elements, then $H=A_4$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Show that if a subgroup $H$ of $A_4$ contains at least $7$ elements, then $H=A_4$.

I can show picking $7$ elements they generate $A_4$, but I don't know how to show it works in every case.

$$A_4=\{1, (123), (132) , (124) , (142) ,(134) , (143) , (234), (243) , (12)(34) , (13)(24) , (14)(23)\}.$$

Comment: Do you know that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group?

Answer (score 5):

You know by Lagrange's theorem, that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.

So in your case,

$$\vert H\vert \mid \vert A_4\vert=\frac{4!}2=12.$$

So if $\vert H\vert\geqslant 7$, then $\vert H\vert=12$, so $H=A_4$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**: The order of $A_4$ is $12$, while the order of $\langle H \rangle$ is at least 7. Assume $\langle H \rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $A_4$ and then use Lagrange's Theorem to obtain a contradiction.